# Searching for US Provisional Patents

Tags: search, us8261231, provisional

US8261231 "claims benefit to U.S. Provisional Patent Application No. 61/472,609, which was filed on Apr. 6, 2011... The contents of the above-identified applications are incorporated by reference in their entirety as if recited in full herein."

I am having difficulty finding the provisional patent application, so that we can examine its contents and know what portions of US8261231 are effective February 14, 2012 and what portions are effective April 6, 2011. Anyone know how we can search for US provisional patents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching in Public Pair http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair for the APPLICATION number 61/472609 gives details of this application. By clicking the continuity data tab you get 13/396,368 filed on 02-14-2012 which is Patented claims the benefit of 61/472,609
13/396,392 filed on 02-14-2012 which is Pending claims the benefit of 61/472,609
PCT/US12/32570 filed on 04-06-2012 which is Published claims the benefit of 61/472,609

You will then have to follow up the daughter documents - in PAIR you can download the full file wrapper if you need to. For the PCT you will have to look in WIPO or ESPACENET, remembering to use the application number.

Comment: OK, that worked. Thanks! Though I find it curious that I am not seeing claims construction in the provisional patent application. I was under the impression that you had claims in one of those too.

Comment: Provisional applications do not need claims. What they do need to be actually useful is to provide adequate support for the claims that are eventuality are filed in the non-provisonal application.

Answer (score 2):

By making a written request to the patent office.

http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s103.html#d0e1338

Comment: Gadzooks, it'd be nice if the USPTO spoke ordinary English... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Pending applications can be searched through [AppFT](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html) (when they have been published).

Just enter 61/472,609 into the field (top left) and hit search. I get exactly one result concerning "SYSTEMS AND METHODS FOR A MOBILE APPLICATION DEVELOPMENT AND DEPLOYMENT PLATFORM". Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: That brings up the patent, which cites the provisional patent application. However, the search does not bring up the provisional patent application itself, unless I am missing something. Thanks, though!